# How does server answer the client's questions?

Tags: servlets, server, client

I'm building a project using JSP/Servlet. It has a support function that allows clients to send questions to server (clients aren't member, no email). Admin will checks and answers the questions and sends it back to the client. So may be not answer immediately, and in that period the client may leaves the website. I don't know how to send the answers for the right client when that client return to the website.
I was thinking about IP address but it can be faked. Anyone have any solution to this problem?
English is not my native language, so my English is very bad. Sorry for that.

Comment: You could create a unique identifier for each clients

Comment: make a login for the clients .. then you can identify them . you have to   be familiar with cookies and sessions in order to do this, is suggest you to work on that.

Comment: @NullSaint and where can i save that identifiers? In local storage?

Comment: @quangtruong94 you wont need to store them use something like the motherboard id of the clients pc which is hard to be changed

Comment: @YassinHajaj not member, no email. i've updated my question

Comment: @NullSaint thanks, i'll try

Comment: no probs @quangtruong94

Answer (score 0):

You have some options to do this:

1. **Use Http Session**
   this is the simplest ways and will be handled automatically by servlet container.
   But if client close the browser or leave for some time, the session will expire and he will get a new session id and can't see the answer.
   This can be done as simple as: `session.setAttribute("question")` and `session.getAttribute("question")`

2.**using cookie or local storage**
When he ask a question, assign a unique Hash key to the client and put it in the cookie or save it in local storage of clients browser. This way client will see the answer if he use the same browser he has used to ask question.
you can even show the hash key to client so he can use it to see his answer in other browsers or even another device.